# i am trying to do reaction role in discord py

Tags: python, discord, bots

I tried to run this code (please see my code below).

**Code:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    Channel = client.get_channel('406473869424328736')
    Text= "REACT TO ME"
    Moji = await Client.send_message(Channel, Text)
    await client.add_reaction(Moji, emoji='question')
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel('406473869424328736')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == "question":
      Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="test")
      await client.add_roles(user, Role)
client.run("NzcxMDQxMzcwNjU5MjI1NjMw.X5mWPA.oiEvo4otmA3lThVzCBxQHunugO4")
Moji = await client.send_message(Channel, Text)
```

However, I received an error that is as follows
**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.send_message()` has been deprecated.

It is replaced with:
`await ctx.message.channel.send('message')`
or you can shorten it to
`await ctx.send('message')`

Also, please do not reveal your bot token to the internet.  I urge you to refresh your token asap.